# webdriver.switchTo().defaultContent() triggers System.InvalidOperationException in IE9

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium 2.15 to drive IE9. Overall, it's been working fine. I've got a weird scenario where a: `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()` is triggering a `System.InvalidOperationException` (the message is "`Unable to get browser (NoSuchDriver)`"). I'm quite certain the browser is up and running, and has in fact driven to the content requested. The content in question is a single line HTML doc:

```
<div id='me'>simple page</div>
```

Is there any reason why SwitchTo().DefaultContent() would fail on such a page?

Comment: I believe this may have something to do with webdriver/IE9 restrictions on protected zone settings. The tricky thing is, it's not clear how to set those up for local machine files.

Comment: Yes Stephen Gross: I think so. It needs settings of protected zone in IE

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I figured it out. It's the known Selenium webdriver IE protected zone issue. The trick is, you have to UNcheck protected mode for all 4 zones. Then, implicitly, protected mode is disabled for "local machine" zone, which fixes the problem.

Comment: can you show us the exact steps to do that? i am in the same situation.